# Sliders whose sum total cannot exceed a specified value

Tags: python, plot, slider, bokeh

Using bokeh, I am trying to use sliders to interact with an array consisting of 12 elements. In the code below, The value of each slider has to be multiplied with the corresponding value in the array (i.e. slider1.value is multiplied with array[0], slider2.value is multiplied with array[1] etc.). Where it gets complicated is that the total sum of all the sliders' value can never exceed 1.0. If you want to increase the value of 1 slider, but the sum of all 12 sliders is 1.0, you have to decrease the value of one or more sliders before you can do so. If the sum total of all the sliders' value is for example 0.67, then you have 0.33 left you can distribute amongst the other sliders before you hit a "limit", and cannot increase them further.

Here is an example of my code:

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, TextInput
from bokeh.palettes import Paired12, Pastel1_3, Bokeh8
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap

from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider, Dropdown, Panel, Tabs, HoverTool, Paragraph

array = [0, 0.25, 0.425, 0.0261420833, 0.035854375, 0.079944375, 0.0368772727, 0.0426204545, 0.228336818,
          0.0216474074, 0.0172977778, 0.0586568889]

callback_array = [0, 0.25, 0.425, 0.0261420833, 0.035854375, 0.079944375, 0.0368772727, 0.0426204545, 0.228336818,
         0.0216474074, 0.0172977778, 0.0586568889]

# Just an example of what the different slider values can be: The elements sum to 1.0.
# slider_values = np.array([0.10, 0.05, 0.03, 0.02, 0.08, 0.12, 0.08, 0.20, 0.12, 0.11, 0.09])

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(array=array, callback_array=callback_array))

slider1 = Slider(start=0, end=2, value=1, step=.05, title="Slider 1")
slider2 = Slider(start=0, end=2, value=1, step=.05, title="Slider 2")
slider3 = Slider(start=0, end=2, value=1, step=.05, title="Slider 3")
slider4 = Slider(start=0, end=2, value=1, step=.05, title="Slider 4")
slider5 = Slider(start=0, end=2, value=1, step=.05, title="Slider 5")
slider6 = Slider(start=0, end=2, value=1, step=.05, title="Slider 6")
slider7 = Slider(start=0, end=2, value=1, step=.05, title="Slider 7")
slider8 = Slider(start=0, end=2, value=1, step=.05, title="Slider 8")
slider9 = Slider(start=0, end=2, value=1, step=.05, title="Slider 9")
slider10 = Slider(start=0, end=2, value=1, step=.05, title="Slider 10")
slider11 = Slider(start=0, end=2, value=1, step=.05, title="Slider 11")
slider12 = Slider(start=0, end=2, value=1, step=.05, title="Slider 12")

callback = CustomJS(
    args=dict(source=source, slider1=slider1, slider2=slider2, slider3=slider3, slider4=slider4, slider5=slider5, slider6=slider6, slider7=slider7, slider8=slider8, slider9=slider9, slider10=slider10, slider11=slider11, slider12=slider12),
    code="""
    let x = source.data['empty']
    let y = source.data['counts'];
    for (let i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        x[0] = y[0] * slider1.value
        x[1] = y[1] * slider2.value
        x[2] = y[2] * slider3.value
        x[3] = y[3] * slider4.value
        x[4] = y[4] * slider5.value
        x[5] = y[5] * slider6.value
        x[6] = y[6] * slider7.value
        x[7] = y[7] * slider8.value
        x[8] = y[8] * slider9.value
        x[9] = y[9] * slider10.value
        x[10] = y[10] * slider11.value
        x[11] = y[11] * slider12.value       
        }

    source.change.emit();
""")

slider1.js_on_change('value', callback)
slider2.js_on_change('value', callback)
slider3.js_on_change('value', callback)
slider4.js_on_change('value', callback)
slider5.js_on_change('value', callback)
slider6.js_on_change('value', callback)
slider7.js_on_change('value', callback)
slider8.js_on_change('value', callback)
slider9.js_on_change('value', callback)
slider10.js_on_change('value', callback)
slider11.js_on_change('value', callback)
slider12.js_on_change('value', callback)

layout = row(column(slider1, slider2, slider3, slider4, slider5, slider6, slider7, slider8, slider9, slider10, slider11, slider12))

show(layout)
```

Comment: Why is JavaScript tagged?

Answer (score 1):

You can sum up the values of the sliders and only make your changes if the sum is greater 1.

In the example below there are only 3 sliders and the figure is not updated, if the value of all three sliders is bigger than 1. If the figure is not updated, a information is printed to the browser console.

It is not possible to deativate the slider. And it is not possible to deactivate only the growing part.

```
from bokeh.plotting import show, output_notebook, figure
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider, ColumnDataSource
output_notebook()

array = [0, 0.25, 0.425]
callback_array = [0, 0.25, 0.425]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    array=array,
    callback_array=callback_array,
    index=list(range(len(array)))
))

sliders = []
for i in range(len(array)):
    sliders.append(Slider(start=0, end=2, value=0.1, step=.05, title=f"Slider {i}"))

callback = CustomJS(
    args=dict(source=source, sliders=sliders),
    code="""
    let x = source.data['array']
    let y = source.data['callback_array'];

    console.log(sliders)
    let slider_sum = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
        slider_sum += sliders[i].value
    }

    if (slider_sum < 1){
        for (let i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
            x[i] = y[i] * sliders[i].value
        }
    }
    else{
        console.log("The maximum of all sliders extends 1. Please reduce a slider first.")
    }
    source.change.emit();
""")


for slider in sliders:
    slider.js_on_change('value', callback)

p = figure(width=300, height=300)
p.line(x='index', y='array', source=source)
layout = column(*sliders, p)

show(layout)
```

[image: line plot with multiple connected sliders]

[image: log in browser console]

I really hope this helps you.